# How to make a war dependent on another war?

Tags: web-services, jboss

I have a war which consumes the services of another war on its load. In jboss application.xml, i have added these war to be deployed. But the war which is dependent is throwing a readtimeout exception (socket connection times out). How should i make this work?

We are currently using Jboss 4.2.3, but in future we plan to migrate to jboss 7.1.1.

So the solution needed should work on both.

Answer (score 0):

**I do not know whether this will work in Jboss 4**, but you could try..

In `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml`, try this (this is for Jboss 5, so modify the schema accordingly)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns:xs="http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema" xs:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd" version="5.1">
    <depends>jboss.web.deployment:war=/important-app</depends>
</jboss-web>
```